# Web Interface lost connection after I alter the oracle password of my database

Tags: oracle

My company has a database for vehicle tracking system. And It has a website for user to log on and use.

After I change the sys and the main user password through "ALTER USER --- identified by' command. The website login became dysfunctional. Our DBA just quit so I have no idea how to troubleshoot.

Is there any guideline I can use?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the application has the passwords either hardcoded or in a configuration file somewhere. If you can find where that is, then simply changing the corresponding values (ie passwords) should resolve the problem. If that doesn't work, you can try to change the password back to the what they were before using the same syntax you used to make the initial change ... "ALTER USER --- identified by ...

Can possibly be more help if you can tell what web server is hosting your site.